twisted python app: Not found (404) page for root requests
I have a following twisted code. However when I run the app I get an error 404 for localhost
I request url:
localhost:8000/

    

The app:
from prometheus_client import Histogram, make_wsgi_app
from twisted.web.server import Site
from twisted.web.wsgi import WSGIResource
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

    metrics_resource = WSGIResource(
            reactor, reactor.getThreadPool(), make_wsgi_app())
    LATENCY_HISTOGRAM = Histogram('hello_world_latency_seconds_h',
            'Time for a request Hello World.',
            buckets=[0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2,  1, 10])
    class HelloWorld(Resource):
          isLeaf = False
          @LATENCY_HISTOGRAM.time()
          def render_GET(self, request):
              return b"Hello World"
    
    root = HelloWorld()
    root.putChild(b'metrics', metrics_resource)
    
    reactor.listenTCP(8000, Site(root))
    reactor.run()

What am I doing wrong?
There are no logs in twisted output

It might help if you included the console output of the script.

Also, what URL did you request?

You're working with Twisted, a Python framework, and encountering an error due to a missing method in your code. Since your HelloWorld class has the isLeaf attribute set to False, Twisted expects that this class can handle child resources.
class HelloWorld(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return b"Hello World!"


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    isLeaf = False
    def render_GET(self, request):
        return b"Hello World!"
    
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        if name == '':
            return self
        else:
            return Resource.getChild(self, name, request)  # Default behavior

By doing either of these, you should prevent Twisted from throwing a 404 error when trying to access the root path or any child paths incorrectly handled by your HelloWorld class.
